# Are there any ways to convert inverse trigonometric values to radicals?

Tags: trigonometry, radicals, inverse-function, cubics

When we solve a cubic equation $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$, the roots are supposed to be in the form of radicals in real numbers or complex realm. However,  if the discriminant is less than 0, the solution is ended up with roots represented by inverse trigonometric function in most cases. For example, the three roots for [$x^3−4x+1=0$](https://uniteasy.com/solver/cubicequation/x%5E3-4x+1=0/) are all in trigonometric form. And the equation [$x^3−2x+1=0$](https://uniteasy.com/solver/cubicequation/x%5E3-2x+1=0/) has 1 rational root, and two other roots that could be in radical form if solved by factorization method or inverse trigonometric values if solved by Cardano's solution and trigonometric method. By comparing their decimals, the roots obtained by two different methods are equal. My question is - are there any general ways to convert these inverse trigonometric values to radicals?

Comment: Don’t inverse trigonometric functions have closed forms in terms of $q\pi,q\in\Bbb Q$ when the input is a radical? Maybe you mean trigonometric functions to radicals

Comment: You might find Section 3 of this write up I did a while ago helpful:
https://github.com/awalls-cx18/cubic/blob/master/doc/cubic_hyp.pdf .

It walks from the hyperbolic function form for the roots of a cubic to the radical form for the roots of the cubic.  (The hyperbolic function form and the trigonometric forms really just differ by a factor of $i$ in the angle.)

Comment: @TymaGaidash  Yes, exactly! I mean  trigonometric functions to radicals. I figured out how to proceed.

Comment: @AndyWalls  thanks for the information. Very interesting work.

Answer (score 1):

For a cubic equation when the discriminant is less than zero, the roots may be expressed in the form of trigonometric function of an angle in inverse trigonometric form if solved by Cardano method. For example, $x^3−2x+1=0$
\begin{cases} x_1=2\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}} \cos \bigg[ \dfrac{1}{3}\cdot \arccos\big(-\dfrac{3}{4}\sqrt{\dfrac{3}{2}}\big)\bigg]   \\  x_2=2\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}} \cos \bigg[ \dfrac{1}{3}\cdot \arccos\big(-\dfrac{3}{4}\sqrt{\dfrac{3}{2}}\big)+\dfrac{2\pi}{3}\bigg]  \\ x_3=2\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}}  \cos \bigg[ \dfrac{1}{3}\cdot \arccos\big(-\dfrac{3}{4}\sqrt{\dfrac{3}{2}}\big)+\dfrac{4\pi}{3} \bigg]   \end{cases}
However, the roots may be given in a very clean radical form if solved by factorization method.
\begin{cases} x_1 = 1\\x_2 =-\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac{\sqrt{5}}{2}  \\   x_3=-\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{\sqrt{5}}{2} \end{cases}
If one of the roots is rational, the trigonometric forms could be converted to radical form.
In this case, given $\cosθ = -\dfrac{3}{4}\sqrt{\dfrac{3}{2}}$
, then  by using the identity $4\cos^3θ-3\cos θ-\cos3θ =0$, $\cos\dfrac{θ}{3}=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{\dfrac{3}{2}}$

Then $x_2 = 2\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{3}} \cos \bigg[ \dfrac{θ}{3} +\dfrac{2\pi}{3}\bigg] =-\dfrac{1}{2}-\dfrac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$

For those cubic equations without rational root, for example, $ x^3−4x+1=0$, the roots look like

\begin{cases} x_1=4\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{3}}\cos \bigg[\dfrac{1}{3}\cdot \arccos\big(-\dfrac{3}{16}\sqrt{3}\big)\bigg]   \\  x_2=4\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{3}} \cos \bigg[ \dfrac{1}{3}\cdot \arccos\big(-\dfrac{3}{16}\sqrt{3}\big)+\dfrac{2\pi}{3}\bigg]  \\ x_3=4\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{3}}  \cos \bigg[ \dfrac{1}{3}\cdot \arccos\big(-\dfrac{3}{16}\sqrt{3}\big)+\dfrac{4\pi}{3} \bigg]   \end{cases}
which may take up broad number of cases, still remains unresolved.